# Webpack without Uglify giving "Unexpected Token ~" with redux-persist

Tags: webpack, redux, uglifyjs

I am trying to add redux-persist to my redux application.

I am using webpack to bundle my javascript, and in development the redux-persist package works as expected. My development config (written in coffeescript) looks like this:

```
    debug: true
    devtool: "eval"
    output:
        path: path.resolve 'app/static/bundles/'
        filename: '[name].js'
        publicPath: "#{devServer}:#{port}/app/static/bundles/"

    plugins: [
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin
        new BundleTracker filename: './webpack/webpack-stats.json'
    ]
```

Before deploying to production I build a "staging" bundle that uses the production NODE_ENV but skips the Uglify plugin step to save time, as I often rebuild this bundle multiple times before deploying. However, if I require `redux-persist` anywhere in my source, building this bundle is successful but the page does not load and I get the error `Unexpected Token ~`, which I have traced to the [`json-stringify-safe`](https://github.com/isaacs/json-stringify-safe) dependency of `redux-persist`. The "staging" config looks like this:

```
    output:
        path: path.resolve 'app/static/dist/'
        filename: '[name].js'
        sourceMapFilename: "[name].map.js"
    debug: false
    cache: false
    devtool: "source-map"

    plugins: [

        new BundleTracker filename: './webpack/webpack-stats-staging.json'

        new webpack.DefinePlugin
            'process.env':
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify 'production'
        new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin

        new ExtractTextPlugin "[name].css"

    ]
```

The only difference between this and my production config is that it does not include Uglify, however when I use this config, everything works:

```
   output:
        path: path.resolve 'app/static/dist/'
        filename: '[name].js'
        sourceMapFilename: "[name].map.js",

    devtool: "source-map"

    debug: false
    plugins: [

        new BundleTracker filename: './webpack/webpack-stats-prod.json'

        new webpack.DefinePlugin
            'process.env':
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify 'production'

        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin

        new ExtractTextPlugin "[name].css"

        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin
            sourceMap: false
            compressor:
                warnings: false


    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem was `devtool:"source-map"` in the staging bundle. Changed to `"eval"` and everything works.